# Installing phpmyadmin and it show wrong dependency for PHP8.0

Tags: php, mysql

When I go to install phpmyadmin it wants to load php8.0. I do not want this, because I did a full purge on php8.0 and am using php7.4

## apt-get install phpmyadmin

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
The following additional packages will be installed:  
 dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql javascript-common libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore php-bz2 php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php8.0-bz2 php8.0-common 
Suggested packages:   
  php-libsodium php-mcrypt php-gmp 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql javascript-common libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore php-bz2 php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php8.0-bz2 php8.0-common   phpmyadmin 
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
Need to get 13.8 MB of archives. After this operation, 57.7 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n Abort.
```

Is there an easy way to correct this?

Comment: Might be an idea to remove PHP8 from your `sources.list`, if you don't need it?